# How can I add list side by side (not by using append)?

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I need to add lists in side ways, not in the below. So I think 'append()' is not appropriate. 'concat()' seems to be adding in side ways, but not working for lists.

Do I need to use concat() to add list side ways? If so, how can I do that with lists?

```
months = range(1,3)

pieces=[]
columns = ['id','q1','q2','q3']

for month in months:
    path = 'C:/Users/uib57309/Desktop/newfolder/01_Survey/month/%d.csv' %month
    frame = pd.read_csv(path, names = columns)

    frame['month'] = month
    pieces.append(frame)

names = pd.concat(pieces)
print(names)
```

I used the append(), so the list was added in the below.

Comment: Do you want `.extend` (see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)?

Comment: a=[1,1,1]
b=[2,2,2]
a+b==[1,1,1,2,2,2]

Answer (score 0):

You can use .extend

eg:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]

a.append(b)
print(a)
[1,2,3,4,[5,6,7,8]]

a.extend(b)
print(a)
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: Thanks. I wrote 'extend', instead of 'concat' in my code, but the error is like this: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'str'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid